# How to download to recorders from URL in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an image list from API, I want to download my device the images from the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `image_downloader` package
https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader

with this package you can download multiple files like this

```
var list = [
  "url1",
  "url2",
  "url3",
];

List<File> files = [];

for (var url in list) {
  try {
    var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);
    var path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId);
    files.add(File(path));
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
setState(() {
  _mulitpleFiles.addAll(files);
});
```

check this out maybe will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear about the issue.
If you have a list of data then you can directly show it on Listview, why you requires to store in the database.

If the scenario like this:
You want save complete data in the local storage you can put all the data inside SQFlite directly by using SQFlite plugin.

TO download any files in Flutter [Check this Example](https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/Download-Large-Files-Pdf-Json-Image-With-Progress-In-Flutter)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have an image list from API, I want to download my device the images from the list